# I was trying to switch between expense and income using switch in flutter

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart

I was working on project that calculate income and expense i used switch in the data entry to identify whether it is income or expense but i must have missed something because i used the bool value to display the item it work at the first entry but in the next entry it changes the first also please help me?

```
`



  // this is the code i was trying to loop 



ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: todayFilteredList.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return data.isIncome == true
                                      ? TransactionTileIncome(
                                          index: index,
                                          expense: todayFilteredList[index],
                                          
                                        )
                                      : TransactionTileExpense(
                                          index: index,
                                          expense: todayFilteredList[index],
                                        );
                                },
                              ),

    
    `
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data.isIncome == true
```

change this into

```
data.isIncome
```

You need not compare variable to true, the expression is already true of false.

Comment: sry it is a mistake the code was written as data.income not data.income == true